# Store key/value pair across AWS lambda calls

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a `event scheduler` in `AWS cloudwatch` which runs my lambda function every 2 min. I want to store some variable from last lambda call which is needed for processing in next lambda call.

Is there any small storage option for this or I have to go for `dynamodb` type storage? Thanks.

Comment: Just store a `.json` file in S3? Or maybe use [AWS Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/)?

Comment: SNS,Kinesis,S3 can all work for you. Based on the size of data and favoring asynchronous behavior you can use SNS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use external storage like S3 or DynamoDB.

Answer (score 1):

You can use AWS:Systems Manager: Parameter Store.

This allows a string of up to 4kb to be stored/retrieved, so you can store a comma-delimited list or whatever you wish, eg JSON.

The Lambda potentially remains loaded when an execution terminates, so in principle you can cache some data in a global variable (initialised to None/NULL etc), and check that value first, but you must update the parameter store in case the cache is empty next time !

Look up "lambda warm start"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Targets[].Input` field to add data to the next event in the [CloudWatch event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-events-rule.html#cfn-events-rule-targets). You can do this easily from the lambda using the aws-sdk of your language, for example in [Nodejs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudWatchEvents.html#putTargets-property)

-- Updated with an example

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const events = new AWS.CloudWatchEvents();

/**
 * Lambda entry point
 */
exports.dostuff = async (request) => {

  let stateData;
  // do your stuff

  await updateIteration(stateData);

}

function getRuleTargets() {
  return events.listTargetsByRule({Rule: eventName}).promise();
}

function updateTargetInput(target, newData) {
  const Input = JSON.stringify(newData)
  const params = {
    Rule: eventName,
    Targets: [
      {
        Arn: target.Arn,
        Id: target.Id,
        Input
      }
    ]
  };
  return events.putTargets(params).promise();
}


function updateIteration(data) {
  return getRuleTargets().then(({Targets}) => {
    // Usually there is only one target but just in case
    const target = Targets.find(...)
    return updateTargetInput(target, data)
  });
}
```

Pros of this approach is that you don't need to setup extra infrastructure, neither fetch the data. This would not be a good approach if the event is been used in other places.

Comment: This about storing state information across calls. Not passing static/same parameters in every invocation.

Comment: You can update the Input field in every lambda call in the same way that you could storage it in S3 or DynamoDB. I will update the response for clarification.

Comment: nice. So if my lambda is setup to be triggered for every new row inserted in a DynamoDB table, where in the event object will this state be stored? and where will the actual event data (DDB row inserted) be stored?

Comment: Well, if you are firing an event for each insert you are probably using DynamoDB Streams that pipes through SNS not Cloudwatch events. In the other hand, if the `Targets[].Input` field is filled the Cloudwatch event is overridden by this data. It is stored by Cloudwatch so you cannot fetch the data by external sources (unless they subscribe to the Cloudwatch event). This is enough for the question though since this data is only required for the next lambda execution. More info in the docs I point to in the main response.